# slickslider not working on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Below is an example I made on jsFiddle to reprodice the problem I am facing. I am firing an init function to create slider after loading dynamic content via ajax. Part of the elements and classes created by slick are added to DOM but does not work.

```js
function top_posts(el){
        var reqUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
        el.children('.loadspan').html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw" style="padding: 0;"></i>');
        $.ajax({
            url: reqUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            }).done(function( data ) {
                el.children('.loadspan').hide();
                if(data != ""){
                  console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function(index) {
                          var output = '<div class="card-out">' +
                                            '<div class="card-bg" style="background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any);"></div>' +
                                            '<div class="card-content">' +
                                                '<div class="card-title">' +
                                                    this.name +
                                                '</div>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>';
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            el.append(output);
                        }, (100 * (index + 1)));
                    });
                    top_slider_init();
                } else{
                    el.children('.loadspan').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
                }
                
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                el.children('.loadspan').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
        return false;
}

  var el = $('.top-posts-slider');
  top_posts(el);


function top_slider_init() {
    $('.top-posts-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        speed: 300,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        variableWidth: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false,
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: false,
        centerPadding: "50px",
        cssEase: "ease-in-out",
        draggable: true,
        fade: false,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        pauseOnFocus: true,
        pauseOnDotsHover: false,
        vertical: false,
        verticalSwiping: false,
        rtl: false,
    });
}
```

```css
.card-out {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.card-bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
.card-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="top-posts-slider">

<div class="loadspan"></div>
</div>
```

any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove `setTimeout` because your content is append to `top-posts-slider` after the load of the slick :

```
function top_posts(el){
        var reqUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
        el.children('.loadspan').html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-fw" style="padding: 0;"></i>');
        $.ajax({
            url: reqUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            }).done(function( data ) {
                el.children('.loadspan').hide();
                if(data != ""){
                        console.log(data);
                    $.each(data, function(index) {
                          var output = '<div class="card-out">' +
                                            '<div class="card-bg" style="background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/any);"></div>' +
                                            '<div class="card-content">' +
                                                '<div class="card-title">' +
                                                    this.name +
                                                '</div>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>';
                        //remove settimeout
                        el.append(output);
                    });
                    top_slider_init();
                } else{
                    el.children('.loadspan').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
                }

            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                el.children('.loadspan').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            });
        return false;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ywuu006w/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what is the loadspan div doing inside of the slider container?  When you slick that it's going to try to use that as a slide.

Beyond that, it looks as if you have a race condition between the markup being built and the slider being initialized.  The slider is being initialized before the content is actually inside of the container.  I also  don't think you need that setTimeout function in there, you should structure it something like

```
    var output = '';
    $.each(data, function(index) {
         output += 'All of your markup';
    }
    el.append(output);               
    top_slider_init();
```